# Two different variables getting same value

Tags: java

I am currently working on a small Java application and I ran into a problem. I create two different variables, but after I run the code, the first variable is getting the same value as the second one. They should be different.

Here is my custom file class:

```
public class MyFile {

    private static String path;
    private static String name;

    private static final String FILE_SEPARATOR = "/";

    public MyFile(String path) {
        System.out.println(path);
        this.path = "";
        this.name = "";
        this.path = /*FILE_SEPARATOR*/path;
        String[] dirs = path.split(FILE_SEPARATOR);
        this.name = dirs[dirs.length - 1];
    }

    public static String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Path: " + path + ", Name: " + name;
    }
}
```

Here I am using the variables:

```
MyFile modelFile = new MyFile("res\\model.dae");
MyFile textureFile = new MyFile("res\\diffuse.png");
System.out.println(modelFile.toString());
System.out.println(textureFile.toString());
```

The output is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/083DK.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `MyFile` class, you declare these fields as `static` fields :

```
private static String path;
private static String name;
```

So you can assign to them a single value as a `static` field is shared among all instances of the class.

You should rather declare these fields as instance fields to have distinct values for each `MyFile` instance :

```
private String path;
private String name;
```

Answer (score 1):

> First you want to know about `static` keyword:
>
> - Attributes and methods(member of a class) can be defined as `static`.
> - `static` members do not belongs to an individual object.
> - `static` members are common to all the instances(objects of the same class).
> - `static` members are stores in static memory(a common memory location which can by everybody).

Becauseof two member variables are `static`. Each objects share the values of these two variables(values are common for every objects).

```
private static String path;
private static String name;
```

Remove the `static` in both variables. Then each and every object will hold a individual values for these variables.

Answer (score 0):

When Defining an Entity class the class variable show be private period. Unless you want to access these variable statically, as in without having to instantiate the class or using getters and setter. If you use getters and setters as you have done above, and clearly made an instance of the class you want  use ensure you don't use static access modifiers for the class variables.

The modified code is-as below.
    package StackOverflowProblemSets;

/**
 * Created by HACKER on 05/06/2017.
 * [Two different variables getting same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370181/two-different-variables-getting-same-value)
 */
public class MyFile {

```
private  String path;
private  String name;

private static final String FILE_SEPARATOR = "/";

public MyFile(String path) {
    System.out.println(path);
    this.path = "";
    this.name = "";
    this.path = /*FILE_SEPARATOR*/path;
    String[] dirs = path.split(FILE_SEPARATOR);
    this.name = dirs[dirs.length - 1];
}

public  String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public  String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Path: " + path + ", Name: " + name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFile modelFile = new MyFile("res\\model.dae");
    MyFile textureFile = new MyFile("res\\diffuse.png");
    System.out.println(modelFile.toString());
    System.out.println(textureFile.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: As futher describe above static variable have no attachement to a particular class instance (object), but your varibales are class variables thus the functionality of your MyFile class relies on them thus static access is a no go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about static and local variables.

Static variables of a class are such variables which are common to all instances of that class and are shared by all of the instances. E.g. if I have a class:

```
public static class myClass{
    public static int staticVar;

    //Constructor
    public myClass(){
        staticVar = 0;
    }
 }
```

and then I have the following code in a `main` method of another class:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    myClass c1, c2;
    c1 = new myClass();
    c2 = new myClass();
    c1.staticVar = 4;
    c2.staticVar = 8;
    System.out.println(c1.staticVar + " " + c2.staticVar);
}
```

then my output will be:

```
8 8
```

This is because the variable `staticVar` is shared by both `c1` and `c2`. First when the statement `c1.staticVar = 4` is executed, the value of `staticVar` for **both** `c1` and `c2` is 4. Then the statement `c2.staticVar = 8` is executed to change the value of `staticVar` of both classes to 8.

So in your problem, you have to make your `name` and `path` variables non-static to give each of your `myFile` instances a different value of the variables.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You problem is second file path is overlap of first file path. So, check this code:

```
    MyFile modelFile = new MyFile("res\\model.dae");
    MyFile textureFile = new MyFile("res\\diffuse.png");


    System.out.println(new MyFile("res\\model.dae"));
    System.out.println(new MyFile("res\\diffuse.png"));
```