# How can I send a variable "getId" to another JFrame "Student_Info"?

Tags: java

I want the value of `getId` variable in my student_info.java `JFrame` by the method it gives me only either `null` or nothing and by the constructor overloading it gives correct value but only when I print the value and when I use that value or when I store that value into a variable still It gives `null`.

1. student_login.java:

   ```
       public String getId;
       private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                             
       ConnectionProvider con = new ConnectionProvider();
       student_Password = new String(this.student_password.getPassword());
       student_Username= this.student_username.getText();
       String getStudentLoginTableId = "select student_id from Student_Login where student_username='"+student_Username+"' and student_password='"+student_Password+"'";
       Connection con1 = con.getConn();
       try {
           Statement stmt = con1.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getStudentLoginTableId);
           while(rs.next()){
               getId = rs.getString("student_id");
           }
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Student_Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);   }
   }
   public String getid(){
   if("101".equals(getId)){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "yes");
   }
   else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no");
   }
   return getId;   }
   ```
2. student_info.java:

   ```
   String a = new Student_Login().getid();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a);
   String get = "select student_id , student_name from student_info where student_id='"+a+"'";
   ConnectionProvider con = new ConnectionProvider();
   Connection con1 = con.getConn();
   try{
       Statement stmt = con1.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(get);
       while(rs.next()){
           i = rs.getString("student_id");
           n = rs.getString("student_name");
       }
       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getId);
       jLabel13.setText(i);
       jLabel14.setText(n);
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Student_Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
   ```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which is your actual problem? Please bee more specific.

Comment: Can you show us your `getId()` and `Student_Info()` implementation.

Comment: And what happen when you try to get `getId` to another frame, Is error occured?

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista I want the value of getId variable in my student_info.java JFrame by the method it gives me only either null or nothing and by the constructor overloading it gives correct value but only when I print the value and when I use that value or when I store that value into a variable still It gives null.

Comment: @Blasanka no errors are occurring but I'm not getting the value of "getId" in student_info.java JFrame I'm getting only null or nothing. if there is another why then please tell. thank you for a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason:**

That because you have two separate classes, one is `student_login` and other one is `student_info`. So to get  value of `getId` you have created  new object from `student_login`.

```
String a = new Student_Login().getid();
```

Keep remember each and every time when you create a object from a class, that class member variable values are individual to the object. In another word vales are not common to the every object that you are creating.

**Solution:**

You need to make `getId` variable to be common for every object. In another word `getId` values should be share among the all objects.

To do this you can use `static` keyword(modifier).

```
public static String getId;
```

[Learn more about `static` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370181/two-different-variables-getting-same-value/44370270#44370270).

Comment: thank you very very very much, sir. I have been facing this problem for a log time you just sort it out in a very short time thanks again.